# How make Reactjs and MDL working together?

Tags: c, reactjs, material-design, typescript1.6

Using material-design-lite (MDL) with reactjs disables catching events on react components , e.g. onClick.

Has someone any clue how to be able to catch synthetic events nevertheless?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at http://material-ui.com?  This is an implementation of Material Design using ReactJS.  I have utilized it on projects before, and it is built to play nicely in the React ecosystem.

Comment: Link only answers are of little use on stack overflow and generally discouraged. Please post a working solution or significant content of your answer in the actual answer. Links should only provider further reference, as they can go dead in the future, making this answer useless for future visitors.

Comment: I disagree - the rules state: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there."  In this case, the question is about material design and its interaction with ReactJS - of which the linked resource is built to play with ReactJS (and, by extension, its synthetic event handling).  Yes, one day the link may die - but the link provided a resource which directly answered the question asked.

Comment: Community consensus as far as I know it is that links should only add to an answer, not be the only informative part of it. When including a link in your answer, ask yourself: "Would this answer still be useful if I didn't include this link?" if no, then you shouldn't post it.